# I have no sound on my headphones, but i have sound on my speakers using Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, laptop, alsa, headphones

I have an Hp pavilion dv6 laptop and my headphones are not working properly.
When i plug them in, there is no sound coming through them. But if i unplug them, the sound comes normally through the speakers.

I tried using alsamixer. And i noticed that when i plug the headphones in, one of the bars comes down. I brought it back up, but when i reboot it goes back to how it was.

Do any of you know a possible solution?

Thanks